# GLM Using Log-gamma Distribution

Tags: generalized-linear-model, gamma-distribution, logarithm

My data are skewed. Using log-normal causes a strong left-skew in the residuals. Using Gamma causes a strong right-skew in the residuals. I thought to myself, why not log transform the data and then use a log-Gamma distribution? Rationale being that the log of a Gamma distribution will have some left-skew (which is what I need to capture given that the log-normal was causing left-skew, presumably because of the properties of the log -> stretches out values below the median). My question is how to go about modeling the mean of the log-Gamma distribution in a GLM-like way? In R,

```
library(actuar)
chk = rlgamma(1e6, shapelog = 3, ratelog = 4)
mean(chk)
```

This is pretty close to,

```
chk2 = rgamma(1e6, shape = 3, rate = 4)
mean(exp(chk2))
```

I know that $\mathbb{E}[\log x] \neq \log \mathbb{E}[x]$, but maybe the bias is negligible in this case or perhaps it depends on the parameter estimates that define the log-Gamma distribution?

If $\mathbb{E}[\log x] \approx \log \mathbb{E}[x]$ in this case, then I can just model the mean similar to a Gamma GLM. Something like,

```
ln_mu = X * beta
nll = -1 * dgamma(log(y), shapelog, ln_mu / shapelog, true) - log(y)
```

Comment: What residuals are you looking at? Pearson? Studentized? A skewed distribution and a model for mean response will produce skewed residuals. None of these findings support picking GLM models from the Rolodex.

Comment: @adamo I looked at randomized quantile residuals to try and mitigate the issue you raised